# Can and how do you access the last bash exit code from a NodeJS app running in bash

Tags: node.js, bash

So the scenario I have here is that I want to be able to run a set of bash commands like so

```
command; nodeapp
```

I want to run the command and then have the nodeapp read the exitcode of the command run before the nodeapp to know if it failed or was successful. How do I do this?

I've looked at `$?` and `$PIPESTATUS` which is what would normally work for a bash script but it appears those environment variables do not get passed to the node application via `process.env`.

How could I accomplish this?

*I know I could just make my nodeapp run a childprocess with the command but it just feels a bit unintuitive to me.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you want the `nodeapp` to read the exit code, but in any case you may put the exit code in a variable and then use it however you want in bash.

`command1;code=$?;....`

Maybe using `&&` and `||` can help for your solution. Examples:

`command1 && command2` #command2 runs only if command1 is successful.

`command1 || command2` #command2 run if command1 is not successful.

Comment: All interesting enough ideas but again they're not really intuitive.

My best solution so far has been to use `command; nodeapp -c $?`

The problem is I want to write a solution that makes it easy to use on the command line. I guess at worst if there isn't a way I can wrap the application in a bash script to pass it in

Also note `command1;code=$?;....` doesn't work, `command1;code=$? nodeapp` does though.